# Filter listview with custom adapter not filtering

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to filter my listview according to what's inputted in my edittext but the listview is not being filtered. Hope there's anyone who can help me. Thank you in advance.

Here's my code for my adapter:

```
public class ListofCityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable{
    int groupid;
    ArrayList<City> records;
    ArrayList<City> items;
    Context context;


    public ListofCityAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, ArrayList<City> objects) {

        super(context, vg, id, objects);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.records = objects;


    } public int getCount() {
        return records.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);

        TextView textName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_name);
        textName.setText(records.get(position).getCityName());
        TextView cityregion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_region);
        cityregion.setText(records.get(position).getRegion());
       ImageView image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        new DownloadImageTask(image).execute(records.get(position).getImage());
        return itemView;

    }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

    }
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<City> results = new ArrayList<City>();
                if (records == null)
                    records = items;
                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (records != null && records.size() > 0) {
                        for (final City g : records) {
                            if (g.getCityName().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                items = (ArrayList<City>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Here's my ListofCity.class. this is

```
public class ListofCity extends Fragment implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    Activity context;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Spinner filter;
    ListofCityAdapter cityAdapter;
    GridView listCity;
    ArrayList<City> records;
    int id;
    EditText search;
     //  SharedPreferences.Editor citylist;
    String line=null;
    String filtering,cityname;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    public ListofCity(){

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listof_city, container, false);

        context = getActivity();
        records = new ArrayList<City>();
        listCity = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.cities);
        cityAdapter = new ListofCityAdapter(context, R.layout.city_layout, R.id.city_name, records);
        listCity.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        search = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        filter = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.filter);
        String categories[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filtering);
        ArrayAdapter<String> cat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        cat.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        filter.setAdapter(cat);
       listCity.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        filter.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(new int[]{android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_orange_light, android.R.color.holo_red_light});

        listCity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), City_attractions.class);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Opening", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cityname = records.get(position).getCityName();
                String info = records.get(position).getDescription();
                String area = records.get(position).getArea();
                String population = records.get(position).getPopulation();
                String region = records.get(position).getRegion();
                String province = records.get(position).getProvince();
                myIntent.putExtra("cityname", cityname);
                myIntent.putExtra("cityinfo", info);
                myIntent.putExtra("cityarea", area);
                myIntent.putExtra("citypopulation", population);
                myIntent.putExtra("cityregion", region);
                myIntent.putExtra("cityprovince", province);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                cityAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            }

            @Override

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,

                                          int arg3) {

            }

            @Override

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }

        });
        return view;

    }




    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        fetchCity fetch = new fetchCity();
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                filtering ="All";
                fetch.execute();
                break;
            case 1:
                filtering ="Alphabetically";
                fetch.execute();
                break;
            case 2:
                filtering ="Region";
                fetch.execute();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }


    private class fetchCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pd.setTitle("Retrieving data");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filter", filtering));
            try
            {
                records.clear();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://igph.esy.es/getcity.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid IP Address",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            try
            {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
            }


            //parse json data
            try {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
                // Remove unexpected characters that might be added to beginning of the string
                result = result.substring(result.indexOf(""));
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    City p = new City();
                    p.setCityName(json_data.getString("cityName"));
                    p.setArea(json_data.getString("area"));
                    p.setPopulation(json_data.getString("population"));
                    p.setImage(json_data.getString("path"));
                    p.setDescription(json_data.getString("city_info"));
                    p.setProvince(json_data.getString("province"));
                    p.setRegion(json_data.getString("region"));

                    records.add(p);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data " + e.toString());

            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (pd != null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
            Log.e("size", records.size() + "");
            cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code where you have a text changed listener that calls `adapter.getFilter().filter(constraint)`.

Comment: hello @kris larson. I've already updated my question. I added my listofcity.class which is a fragment.Thanks

Comment: So when you change the spinner the city list updates correctly and everything, but when you type something you don't see the list update from the filter?

Comment: It's just not jumping out at me right now, I'll take another look later tonight...